# In a SQL pairing system, how do I avoid overmatching from lag?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm planning out a very lightweight helpdesk system in PHP/MySQL where several live agents will be listed in a table, with a flag set that they can be matched to a user for conversation.

My worry is that in the time between selecting an open agent and updating the record with the next query, it's possible that another user will have executed the select and grabbed the same agent.

It's not something I expect to be a huge problem outside of heavy load, but it's still a worry. I'm sure this problem has been addressed before, but I'm not sure where to look to find it. How can I avoid double pairing?

Comment: Please read one of my answers on [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61603/how-to-query-and-increase-a-value-counter-in-a-thread-safe-way-avoid-race-co/61605#61605) which answers your question.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, and I believe the DAL I wrote around PDO for this project will be able to handle it without any modification. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is resolved by using (My)SQL [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) years ago. That means that in your case the tables structure should use [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) engine, and, for simplicity, speed and security you should use [prepared](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) SQL statements (with [PHP PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is pretty easy).

Comment: I actually already wrote an abstraction layer for PDO for this particular project, and I think it will do transactions fine without modification.